# How To restrict a user to access the SQL Server database from client Local Machine?

Tags: sql-server, security

I have developed an application in Asp. Net C# Technology. It is an offline application.
I need to host my application with the SQL Server database locally on the client's machine. The client can easily access the database from the web.config connection string.

I want to restrict the client or any other user to access/see the database.

How can I do this?

Comment: The closest you can come is storing the data encrypted and embedding the encryption key in the application. Even that can of course always be reverse engineered by someone sufficiently dedicated. Permissions are tied to users, not applications -- if an application running on behalf of a user can do something, then the user can also always do it without the application.

Comment: In asp.net you can encrypt configuration sections within a web.config.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/53tyfkaw(v=vs.100)

Comment: @squillman thanks for the solution. I have gone through this link. It is really useful to hide database information from application-level but as per this link, any user can be an admin via windows auth and access the database from SQL Server.  
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/connect-to-sql-server-when-system-administrators-are-locked-out?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Yes, it only makes it harder.  But at the end an admin can get in.

Comment: I deny access of window authentication. Now user can only access the database with the credentials that are there in the connection string in web.config. 
Now, If I encrypt the web.config then the user won't be able to access the database even with server authentication. What do you think about this scenario @squillman Sir?

Comment: Probably about the best you're going to get.  They'll still be able to get in if they really really want to, but...

Answer (score 0):

> I need to host my application with the SQL Server database locally on the client's machine
> I want to restrict the client or any other user to access/see the database.
>
> How can I do this?

You cannot.  It's the client's machine, so it's the client's SQL Server, and the client's database.

Here are the instructions for any Windows Administrator to connect to SQL Server with full administrative permissions: [Connect to SQL Server When System Administrators Are Locked Out](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/connect-to-sql-server-when-system-administrators-are-locked-out?view=sql-server-ver15)